# infer a type for common fields in two records

Tags: haskell, purescript, recordtype, row-polymorphism

Bear with me if this is a foolish question. How can I **type** a generic function that takes two records and returns an array of their common fields?

Let's say I have:

```
type A = { name :: String, color :: String }
type B = { name :: String, address :: Address, color :: String }

myImaginaryFunction :: ???
-- should return ["name", "color"] :: Array of [name color]
```

I want to write a function that takes **ANY** two types of records and return an array of common fields. A haskell solution would work as well.

Comment: Without some advanced techniques, that kind of information just isn't available from a value. Why do you think you *need* `myImaginaryFunction`?

Comment: @chepner, Because I have records and I wanna see what's common in there? I don't understand why I don't need it.

Comment: What would you do with such a list of strings?

Comment: @chepner, show them on the UI. :)

Comment: Your UI shouldn't be exposing type information. You want to store the field names as data, not static functions (which is what such field labels really are).

Comment: @chepner, a field `name` _is_ `data` not a type. Its `type` is type.

Comment: `name` is a function of type `A -> String` (or `B -> String`; you need a language extension to even allow `name` to be used in both `A` and `B`). It's not an attribute that you can somehow query from a value of type `A` (or `B`).

Comment: (*Completely* ignoring the fact that `type A = { name :: String, color :: String }` is not even valid Haskell.)

Comment: @chepner, originally posted as a `PureScript` question but then I cheated a little to get a more views. So you're saying there is no such [keys](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/keys) in Haskell?

Comment: There is, but you need to use something like `newtype A = A {name :: String, color :: String}`. The point stands, though, that you can't (easily) introspect the list of field names from a value of type `A`.

Comment: @chepner, Thanks. Not values. I have defined types. But imagine I have 100 `A`, `B`, `C`, ... types. Not sure if I'm asking this correctly.

Comment: @norbertpy You want to look at the `Generic` typeclass (I'm not sure if it exists in PureScript, I hope it does). This is the standard approach for things like generating JSON serialization. It should be fairly easy to adapt this for your purposes. I'd offer a Haskell answer, but it would be very tied to the particulars of `GHC.Generics` or `syb` (I don't know if PureScript has that either).

Comment: Please make it clear what language you're aiming a question at. If you tag it with Haskell, clarify how your question relates to it. In Haskell, this whole idea really doesn't make much sense. If you consider types as more or less dictionaries, then this can at best be dependently-typed, which Haskell doesn't do. You can not even really give multiple different record types fields with the same name. There are some ways you could trick something similar to work in modern GHC, but it's highly questionable if it's sensible. In PureScript – no idea.

Comment: Also, if the choice of "Haskell-like" language doesn't matter to you, consider looking at http://elm-lang.org instead.  It actually has support for the kind of record-based structural typing you seem to want to do.  (Though I think writing type-level functions to automatically find lists of common fields is still off the table.)

Comment: @K.A.Buhr PureScript also has record-based structural typing, but it's a lot less restrictive than Elm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To express two record types with common fields in Haskell, you'll need a GHC extension:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DuplicateRecordFields #-}
```

and to introspect the names of the fields, you'll need generics based on the `Data` class:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveDataTypeable #-}
import Data.Data ( Data, Typeable, DataRep(AlgRep), dataTypeRep
                 , dataTypeOf, constrFields)
import Data.List (intersect)
import Data.Proxy (Proxy(..), asProxyTypeOf)
```

This will allow you to define two data types using the same field names:

```
data Address = Address String deriving (Typeable, Data)
data A = A { name :: String, color :: String }
    deriving (Typeable, Data)
data B = B { name :: String, address :: Address, color :: String}
    deriving (Typeable, Data)
```

and then you can retrieve the field names using:

```
fieldNames :: (Data t) => Proxy t -> [String]
fieldNames t = case dataTypeRep $ dataTypeOf $ asProxyTypeOf undefined t of
  AlgRep [con] -> constrFields con
```

and get the common fields with:

```
commonFields :: (Data t1, Data t2) => Proxy t1 -> Proxy t2 -> [String]
commonFields t1 t2 = intersect (fieldNames t1) (fieldNames t2)
```

After which the following will work:

```
ghci> commonFields (Proxy :: Proxy A) (Proxy :: Proxy B)
["name", "color"]
ghci>
```

Note that the implementation of `fieldNames` above assumes that only record types with a single constructor will be introspected.  See the documentation for `Data.Data` if you want to generalize it.

Now, because you're a help vampire, I know that you will demand a type level function, even though you said nothing in your question about requiring a type-level function!  In fact, I can see you've already added a comment about how you're interested in somehow returning an array of `name | color` though no such thing exists in Haskell and even though you explicitly said in your question that you expected the term-level answer `["name", "color"]`.

Still, there may be non-vampires with a similar question, and perhaps this answer will help them instead.

Comment: Hah, thanks very much for the answer. This is great.

Comment: Seems like I need dependent-types which nor Haskell neither Elm or PureScript support.

Answer (score 4):

For Haskell, I like K.A. Buhr's answer, but personally I would not use Typeable and instead reach for GHC Generics. I think that might be preference at this point though.

For PureScript, I wrote about this kind of problem in my blog post [Making Diffs of differently-typed Records in PureScript](https://qiita.com/kimagure/items/ca229cb4ba76db0c24a8) earlier this month. The approach is completely different from what you have with languages that don't have row types (No, Elm does not have these. You really don't get a solution there other than to use a homogeneous String Map).

First off, if you're at all familiar with PureScript, you might want to use [Union](https://pursuit.purescript.org/builtins/docs/Prim#t:Union), but this won't work either, as you'd want to do something like:

```
Union r1' r r1
```

Where `r1'` would be the complement of the shared subtype `r` between your first record `r1` and `r2`. The reason being that you have two unsolved variables here, and the functional dependencies of Union require that any two of three parameters of Union be solved for.

So since we can't use Union directly, we'll have to craft some kind of solution. Since I can get a RowList structure that is sorted by keys, I opted to use this to walk through the two different records' RowLists and get out the intersection:

```
class RowListIntersection
  (xs :: RowList)
  (ys :: RowList)
  (res :: RowList)
  | xs ys -> res

instance rliNilXS :: RowListIntersection Nil (Cons name ty tail) Nil
instance rliNilYS :: RowListIntersection (Cons name ty tail) Nil Nil
instance rliNilNil :: RowListIntersection Nil Nil Nil
instance rliConsCons ::
  ( CompareSymbol xname yname ord
  , Equals ord EQ isEq
  , Equals ord LT isLt
  , Or isEq isLt isEqOrLt
  , If isEq xty trashty yty
  , If isEq xty trashty2 zty
  , If isEq (SProxy xname) trashname (SProxy zname)
  , If isEq
      (RLProxy (Cons zname zty res'))
      (RLProxy res')
      (RLProxy res)
  , If isEqOrLt
      (RLProxy xs)
      (RLProxy (Cons xname xty xs))
      (RLProxy xs')
  , If isLt
      (RLProxy (Cons xname yty ys))
      (RLProxy ys)
      (RLProxy ys')
  , RowListIntersection xs' ys' res'
  ) => RowListIntersection (Cons xname xty xs) (Cons yname yty ys) res
```

Then I used a short definition for getting the keys of the resulting RowList out:

```
class Keys (xs :: RowList) where
  keysImpl :: RLProxy xs -> List String

instance nilKeys :: Keys Nil where
  keysImpl _ = mempty

instance consKeys ::
  ( IsSymbol name
  , Keys tail
  ) => Keys (Cons name ty tail) where
  keysImpl _ = first : rest
    where
      first = reflectSymbol (SProxy :: SProxy name)
      rest = keysImpl (RLProxy :: RLProxy tail)
```

So together, I can define a function like so to get the shared labels:

```
getSharedLabels
  :: forall r1 rl1 r2 rl2 rl
  . RowToList r1 rl1
  => RowToList r2 rl2
  => RowListIntersection rl1 rl2 rl
  => Keys rl
  => Record r1
  -> Record r2
  -> List String
getSharedLabels _ _ = keysImpl (RLProxy :: RLProxy rl)
```

Then we can see results we expect:

```
main = do
  logShow <<< Array.fromFoldable $
    getSharedLabels
      { a: 123, b: "abc" }
      { a: 123, b: "abc", c: true }
  -- logs out ["a","b"] as expected
```

If you're new to RowList/RowToList, you might consider reading through my [RowList Fun With PureScript 2nd Edition](https://speakerdeck.com/justinwoo/rowlist-fun-with-purescript-2nd-edition) slides.

I put the code for this answer [here](https://github.com/justinwoo/shared-labels-two-records/blob/master/src/Main.purs).

If all this seems too involved, your other solution may be to coerce the records into a String Map and get the set union of the keys. I don't know if this is an answer in Elm though, since the runtime representation of a String Map probably does not match Record's. But for PureScript, this is one option as StrMap's runtime representation is the same as a Record.

Comment: The OP said he doesn't want an array returned (or, I presume, a list), because, quote, "Array doesn't enforce anything". But he failed to specify what exactly he does want.

Comment: @FyodorSoikin, I said _Array of String_ doesn't enforce anything. Array of Color enforces that I will have Colors in there.

Comment: Still too much ceremony for such a simple task. And you Haskell-people never lose an opportunity to make snarky comment. This guy LOLed on his twitter account while you feel you were disrespected and started downvoting. Such a horrible community.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, after giving this some more thought, I guess it *is* possible to do what you *actually* want to do in modern Haskell, if what you *actually* want to do is work with a record type with named fields at the type level, including doing things like compile-time derivation of a new record type using the common fields from two other records.

It's a little involved and a little ugly, though some bits work surprisingly well.  Yes, of course it's "too much ceremony for such a simple task", but bear in mind that we're trying to implement a brand new, non-trivial, type-level feature (a sort of dependent structural typing).  The only way to make this a simple task is to bake the feature into the language and its type system from the beginning; otherwise, it's going to be complicated.

Anyway, until we get the `DependentTypes` extension, you have to enable a small number (ha ha) of extensions explicitly:

```
{-# LANGUAGE AllowAmbiguousTypes       #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs                     #-}
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures            #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables       #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell           #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications          #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies              #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeInType                #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators             #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances      #-}
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -Wincomplete-patterns  #-}

module Records where
```

We'll make a fair bit of use of the `singletons` package and its submodules: the `Prelude` for basic type-level functions like `Map`, `Fst`, and `Lookup`; the `TH` module for generating our own singleton and promoted functions with Template Haskell splices; and `TypeLits` for working with the `Symbol` type (i.e., string literals at the type level).

```
import Data.Singletons.Prelude
import Data.Singletons.TH
import Data.Singletons.TypeLits
```

We'll also need some other odds and ends.  `Text` is only needed because it's the unlifted ("demoted") version of `Symbol`.

```
import Data.Function ((&))
import Data.Kind (Type)
import Data.List (intersect)
import qualified Data.Text as Text
```

We won't be able to work with usual Haskell records.  Instead, we'll define a `Record` type constructor.  This type constructor will be indexed by a list of `(Symbol, Type)` pairs, where the `Symbol` gives the field name, and the `Type` gives the type of the value stored in that field.

```
data Record :: [(Symbol, Type)] -> Type where
```

Already, there are several major implications to this design decision:

- The same field name in different record types can refer to different field value types.
- Fields are ordered in the record, so record types are only the same if they have the same fields, with the same types, in the same *order*.
- The same field can appear multiple times in a record, even though the accessor function we provide will only access one (the last added).

In dependently typed programs, design decisions tend to run deep.  If, for example, the same field could not appear multiple times, we would need to find a way to reflect that in the type and then make sure that all our functions were able to supply appropriate proof that a duplicate field wasn't being added.

Anyway, back to our `Record` type constructor.  There will be two data constructors, a `Record` constructor to create an empty record:

```
  Record :: Record '[]
```

and a `With` constructor to add a field to a record:

```
  With :: SSymbol s -> t -> Record fs -> Record ('(s, t) : fs)
```

Note that `With` requires a runtime representative for the `s :: Symbol` in the form of a symbol singleton `SSymbol s`  The convenience function `with_` will make this singleton implicit:

```
with_ :: forall s t fs . (SingI s) => t -> Record fs -> Record ('(s, t) : fs)
with_ = With sing
```

with the idea that by allowing ambiguous types and using type application, we expose the following reasonably succint syntax for defining records.  The explicit type signatures are not necessary here but are included to make it clear what's being created:

```
rec1 :: Record '[ '("bar", [Char]), '("foo", Int)]
rec1 = Record & with_ @"foo" (10 :: Int)
              & with_ @"bar" "Hello, world"
-- i.e., rec1 = { foo = 10, bar = "Hello, world" } :: { foo :: Int, bar :: String }

rec2 :: Record '[ '("quux", Maybe Double), '("foo", Int)]
rec2 = Record & with_ @"foo" (20 :: Int)
              & with_ @"quux" (Just 1.0 :: Maybe Double)
-- i.e., rec2 = { foo = 20, quux = Just 1.0 } :: { foo :: Int, quux :: Maybe Double }
```

To prove that this record type is useful, we'll define a type-safe field accessor.  Here's one that uses an explicit singleton to select the field:

```
field :: forall s t fs . (Lookup s fs ~ Just t) => SSymbol s -> Record fs -> t
field s (With s' t r)
  = case s %:== s' of
      STrue -> t
      SFalse -> field s r
```

and a helper with an implict singleton:

```
field_ :: forall s t fs . (Lookup s fs ~ Just t, SingI s) => Record fs -> t
field_ = field @s sing
```

which is intended to be used with a type application like so:

```
exField = field_ @"foo" rec1
```

Note that trying to access a nonexistent field won't type-check.  The error message isn't ideal, but at least it's a compile-time error:

```
-- badField = field_ @"baz" rec1  -- gives: Couldn't match type Nothing with Just t
```

The definition of `field` gives a hint of the power of the `singletons` library.  We're using the type-level `Lookup` function which has been automatically generated via Template Haskell from a term-level definition that looks exactly like the following (taken from the `singletons` source and renamed to avoid conflicts):

```
lookup'                  :: (Eq a) => a -> [(a,b)] -> Maybe b
lookup' _key []          =  Nothing
lookup'  key ((x,y):xys) = if key == x then Just y else lookup' key xys
```

Using only the context `Lookup s fs ~ Just t`, GHC is able to determine that:

1. Because the context implies this field will be found in the list, the second argument of `field` can never be the empty record `Record`, so there is no warning about incomplete patterns for `field`, and in fact you'll get a type error if you try to handle this as a runtime error by adding the case: `field s Record = error "ack, something went wrong!"`
2. The recursive call to `field` is type-correct if we're in the `SFalse` branch.  That is, GHC has figured out that if we can successfully `Lookup` the key `s` in the list but it's not at the head, we must be able to look it up in the tail.

(This is amazing to me, but anyway...)

Those are the basics of our record type.  To introspect field names at either runtime or compile time, we'll introduce a helper, which we'll lift to the type level (i.e., the type-level function `Names`) using Template Haskell:

```
$(singletons [d|
  names :: [(Symbol, Type)] -> [Symbol]
  names = map fst
  |])
```

Note that the type-level function `Names` can provide compile-time access to the field names of the record, for example in the hypothetical type signature:

```
data SomeUIType fs = SomeUIType -- a UI for the given compile-time list of fields
recordUI :: Record fs -> SomeUIType (Names fs)
recordUI _ = SomeUIType
```

More likely, though, we'll want to work with field names at runtime.  Using `Names`, we can define the following function to take a record and return its list of field names as a singleton.  Here, `SNil` and `SCons` are the singleton equivalents of the terms `[]` and `(:)`.

```
sFields :: Record fs -> Sing (Names fs)
sFields Record = SNil
sFields (With s _ r) = SCons s (sFields r)
```

And here's a version that returns a `[Text]` instead of a singleton.

```
fields :: Record fs -> [Text.Text]
fields = fromSing . sFields
```

Now, if you just want to get a runtime list of common fields of two records, you can do:

```
rec12common = intersect (fields rec1) (fields rec2)
-- value:  ["foo"]
```

What about creating a type with common fields at compile time?  Well, we can define the following function to get the left-biased set of fields with common names.  (It's "left-biased" in the sense that if matching fields in two records have different types, it'll take the type of the first record.)  Again, we use the `singletons` package and Template Haskell to lift it to a type-level `Common` function:

```
$(singletons [d|
  common :: [(Symbol,Type)] -> [(Symbol,Type)] -> [(Symbol,Type)]
  common [] _ = []
  common (x@(a,b):xs) ys
    = if elem a (map fst ys)
      then x:common xs ys
      else   common xs ys
  |])
```

This allows us to define a function that takes two records and reduces the first record to the set of fields with the same name as fields in the second record:

```
reduce :: Record fs1 -> Record fs2 -> Record (Common fs1 fs2)
reduce Record _ = Record
reduce (With s x r1) r2
  = case sElem s (sFields r2) of STrue  -> With s x (reduce r1 r2)
                                 SFalse -> reduce r1 r2
```

Again, the singletons library is really remarkable here.  I'm using my automatically generated `Common` type-level function together with the singleton-level `sElem` function (which is automatically generated within the `singletons` package from a term-level definition of the `elem` function).  Somehow, through all this complexity, GHC can figure out that if `sElem` evaluates to `STrue`, I must include `s` in the list of common fields, while if it evaluates to `SFalse`, I must not.  Try fiddling with the case results on the right-hand side of the arrows -- you can't get them to type check if you get them wrong!

Anyway, I can apply this function to my two example records.  Again, the type signature is not needed but is given to show what's being produced:

```
rec3 :: Record '[ '("foo", Int)]
rec3 = reduce rec1 rec2
```

Like any other record, I have runtime access to its field names and compile-time type-checking of field access:

```
-- fields rec3           gives  ["foo"], the common field names
-- field_ @"foo" rec3    gives  10, the field value for rec1
```

Note that, in general, `reduce r1 r2` and `reduce r2 r1` will return not just different values, but different *types* if the order and/or types of the commonly names fields differ between `r1` and `r2`.  Changing this behavior would probably require revisiting those early and far-reaching design decisions I mentioned earlier.

For convenience, here's the entire program, tested using Stack lts-10.5 (with singletons 2.3.1):

```
{-# LANGUAGE AllowAmbiguousTypes       #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs                     #-}
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures            #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables       #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell           #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications          #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies              #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeInType                #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators             #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances      #-}
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -Wincomplete-patterns  #-}

module Records where

import Data.Singletons.Prelude
import Data.Singletons.TH
import Data.Singletons.TypeLits
import Data.Function ((&))
import Data.Kind (Type)
import Data.List (intersect)
import qualified Data.Text as Text

data Record :: [(Symbol, Type)] -> Type where
  Record :: Record '[]
  With :: SSymbol s -> t -> Record fs -> Record ('(s, t) : fs)

with_ :: forall s t fs . (SingI s) => t -> Record fs -> Record ('(s, t) : fs)
with_ = With sing

rec1 :: Record '[ '("bar", [Char]), '("foo", Int)]
rec1 = Record & with_ @"foo" (10 :: Int)
              & with_ @"bar" "Hello, world"
-- i.e., rec1 = { foo = 10, bar = "Hello, world" } :: { foo :: Int, bar :: String }

rec2 :: Record '[ '("quux", Maybe Double), '("foo", Int)]
rec2 = Record & with_ @"foo" (20 :: Int)
              & with_ @"quux" (Just 1.0 :: Maybe Double)
-- i.e., rec2 = { foo = 20, quux = Just 1.0 } :: { foo :: Int, quux :: Maybe Double }

field :: forall s t fs . (Lookup s fs ~ Just t) => SSymbol s -> Record fs -> t
field s (With s' t r)
  = case s %:== s' of
      STrue -> t
      SFalse -> field s r

field_ :: forall s t fs . (Lookup s fs ~ Just t, SingI s) => Record fs -> t
field_ = field @s sing

exField = field_ @"foo" rec1
-- badField = field_ @"baz" rec1  -- gives: Couldn't match type Nothing with Just t

lookup'                  :: (Eq a) => a -> [(a,b)] -> Maybe b
lookup' _key []          =  Nothing
lookup'  key ((x,y):xys) = if key == x then Just y else lookup' key xys

$(singletons [d|
  names :: [(Symbol, Type)] -> [Symbol]
  names = map fst
  |])

data SomeUIType fs = SomeUIType -- a UI for the given compile-time list of fields
recordUI :: Record fs -> SomeUIType (Names fs)
recordUI _ = SomeUIType

sFields :: Record fs -> Sing (Names fs)
sFields Record = SNil
sFields (With s _ r) = SCons s (sFields r)

fields :: Record fs -> [Text.Text]
fields = fromSing . sFields

rec12common = intersect (fields rec1) (fields rec2)
-- value:  ["foo"]

$(singletons [d|
  common :: [(Symbol,Type)] -> [(Symbol,Type)] -> [(Symbol,Type)]
  common [] _ = []
  common (x@(a,b):xs) ys
    = if elem a (map fst ys)
      then x:common xs ys
      else   common xs ys
  |])

reduce :: Record fs1 -> Record fs2 -> Record (Common fs1 fs2)
reduce Record _ = Record
reduce (With s x r1) r2
  = case sElem s (sFields r2) of STrue  -> With s x (reduce r1 r2)
                                 SFalse -> reduce r1 r2

rec3 :: Record '[ '("foo", Int)]
rec3 = reduce rec1 rec2
-- fields rec3           gives  ["foo"], the common field names
-- field_ @"foo" rec3    gives  10, the field value for rec1
```

Answer (score -1):

Well, since your function really returns an array of string, then the return type should just be `Array String`.

Types of arguments would be genetic, since you don't know types in advance. If you really want to make sure that these types are actually records, you can make your generic parameters not records themselves, but *type rows*, and then type value parameters as `Record a`.

So:

```
myImaginaryFunction :: forall a b. Record a -> Record b -> Array String
```

This is how you **type** such function.

Or was your question really about how to **implement** it?

Also: have you noticed how cheating (by adding Haskell tag) didn't really bring you any help, but only some scolding? Please don't do this. Respect the community.

Comment: I'm more interested in type-level functions. `Array String`, doesn't enforce anything. I cannot be sure if the string value is really part of my record fields. Array of `name | color` is what I expect.

Comment: Regarding, the cheat, I'm getting familiar with type systems to see how they solve a very simplistic problem. Haskell, ELM, PureScript is irrelevant. They all seem to struggle the same way.

Comment: How are you not interested in `Array String` when you mentioned it yourself right there in your question, as the expected return type of your function?!

Comment: Updated to avoid confusion. But you _knew_ what I meant.